# ASP.NET MVC form element name generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class UserListVM
{
    public SearchModel SearchModel { get; set; }
    public PagedList<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class SearchModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    /* other properties */
}
```

I send UserListVM to my view but the action accepts `SearchModel`:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel filter)
{
        UserListVM model = new UserListVM();

        model.Users = userService.GetUsers(filter);
        model.SearchModel = filter;

        return View(model);
}
```

My view is:

```
@model UserListVM 

<form>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.SearchModel.Text)
</form>
```

But this generates:

```
<input id="SearchModel_Text" name="SearchModel.Text" type="text" value="">
```

Which sends `UserListVM` to the action instead of `SearchModel`. How can I get it to generate this:

```
<input id="Text" name="Text" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Why are you passing a UserListVM to the view when it needs a SearchModel?  Your view doesn't use the anything but the SearchModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchModel.Text, new { id = "Text" })
```

Utilize the overloaded `TextBoxFor()` method that takes a second `object` parameter (called `htmlAttributes`).  Here you can specify HTML attributes to apply to the DOM element you are currently utilizing (in this case, your `input` element).

**Edit**: I believe your lambda expression is wrong.  Change:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.SearchModel.Text)
```

To

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchModel.Text)
// htmlAttributes omitted to show the issue
```

**Edit Edit**: it turns out that even with a specified `name` attribute, it will be rendered according to what the form is requiring for a `POST` to the necessary field(s).

**Edit Edit Edit**: Try to be explicit with `FormExtensions.BeginForm()`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchModel.Text)
}
```

Use this as a substite of your `<form />` element.

Comment: With `LabelFor`, I need to give the Id to it as a string?

Comment: @Lolcoder If I am understanding your question correctly, then yes.  Think of that `object` (`htmlAttributes`) as a direct way to set values for HTML element attributes.

Comment: When I tried this, only the id was changed, somehow the name didn't get overridden.

Comment: @Lolcoder Oh, I see that as well.  I think this probably has to do with MVC overriding that.  It has to be generated as "SearchModel.Text" so that it is bound to your Model.

Comment: @Lolcoder I think you have a deeper underlying problem.  See my edit.  Instead of your lambda expression being `m => Model.SearchModel.Text`, it needs to be `m => m.SearchModel.Text`.  Try that out and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a partial view for your SearchModel, and call it using Html.Partial. Then, from within that partial view, do all of the EditorFor/TextBoxFor Extensions

Your view - UserList.cshtml:

```
@model UserListVM

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("Search", Model.SearchModel)
}
```

Your view - Search.cshtml:

```
@model SearchModel

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumming there is more the the View than you have shown, why not just have your Search method take the UserListVM model.  It will just contain a null reference to the users, so there is no extra data sent in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it manually like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Text", Model.SearchModel.Text)
```